# Unable to load TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I'm following a getting started with python and ML tutorial. IDE in use is Pycharm
here is a list of actions I have performed using anaconda prompt
1)`conda create -n tensor python=3.7`
2)`activate tensor`
3)`pip install tensorflow`
4)`pip install keras`

now I'm try to execute following code in pycharm
`import tensorflow`
but getting following error

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\pythonw.exe "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/Tensor flow test4/test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", l## Heading ##ine 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/Tensor flow test4/test.py", line 1, in 
    import tensorflow
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 101, in 
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core__init__.py", line 40, in 
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 50, in **getattr**
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.**name**)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python__init__.py", line 49, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in 
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: What is the version of tensorflow ?

Comment: Name: tensorflow

Version: 2.1.0

Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.

License: Apache 2.0

Comment: try downgrading it to tensorflow 2.0

Comment: Can you succesfully run `python -c "import tensorflow"` in your terminal after doing `conda activate tensor`?

Comment: same error pooped up, which is mentioned in question